# MSYS2 pip install numpy failed

Tags: numpy, pip, msys2

I am new to MSYS2, so I tried to install numpy using pip (mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pip-9.0.1-3), but the the installation is failed. Here is the output:

(...)
C compiler: x86_64-pc-msys-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe

```
compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c'
x86_64-pc-msys-gcc: _configtest.c
/usr/bin/bash: x86_64-pc-msys-gcc: command not found
/usr/bin/bash: x86_64-pc-msys-gcc: command not found
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/setup.py", line 394, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/setup.py", line 386, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
    return distutils_install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 551, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 314, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 314, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4nnf7xbj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3d852664/numpy/

I have already build tools installed: I used the tutorial on https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2 (I only 64-bit packages)

I looked for similar issues on the net but I found nothing relevant.
Any comment or suggestion is welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The proper gcc compiler has not been installed. For my installation, I used the msys2 shell (not mingw) and installed the msys/gcc package:

```
pacman -S msys/gcc
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-scipy
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python-scipy
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please add quote tags and provide some information which of the two cases covers which problems?

Comment: Installing the proper binary packages solves the problem of "getting numpy" - not strictly the "pip install failed" but at least in my case this was the correct solution.

Comment: Just a note, these are not MSYS2 packages, they are MINGW64 packages - that means, they will run only with `python` in MINGW64 shell (`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe`), but not with `python` in MSYS2 shell (which is `C:\msys64\usr\bin\python3.exe`)